# VHDL: Integrator/Accumulator Won't Subtract

Tags: vhdl

This feels pretty silly but I've been trying a bunch of things for a while now and I can't figure out why this accumulator/integrator can never decrease. It can hold its value or increase, but it never decreases even when fed with negative inputs. Does anyone have any idea?

```
entity Integrator is

    generic(    Max : integer   := integer'high;    --upper limit to saturate "Output" at
                Min : integer   := integer'low);    --lower limit to saturate "Output" at
                
    port(   Input       : in    integer;
            Output      : out   integer := 0;
            Sample      : in    std_logic;  --clock enable
            Reset       : in    std_logic;  --reset 'Output' to zero
            Clock       : in    std_logic);
            
end entity Integrator;

architecture Behavioural of Integrator is
    
    begin
    
        Process_Integrate : process(Clock)
            begin
                if rising_edge(Clock) then
                    if Reset then
                        Output <= 0;
                    elsif Sample then
                        Output <= Output + Input;
                    end if;
                end if;
        end process Process_Integrate;
        
end architecture Behavioural;
```

**UPDATE:**

Hmmm...still not able to decrease with negative input without reading from the Output and disabling VHDL-2008...

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

entity Integrator is

    generic(    Max : integer   := integer'high;    --upper limit to saturate "Output" at
                Min : integer   := integer'low);    --lower limit to saturate "Output" at
                
    port(   Input       : in    integer;
            Output      : out   integer := 0;
            Sample      : in    std_logic;  --clock enable
            Reset       : in    std_logic;  --reset 'Output' to zero
            Clock       : in    std_logic);
            
end entity Integrator;

architecture Behavioural of Integrator is

    signal Accumulator      :  integer := 0;
    
    begin
    
        Process_Integrate : process(Clock)
            begin
                if rising_edge(Clock) then
                    if Reset = '1' then
                        Accumulator <= 0;
                    elsif Sample = '1' then
                          Accumulator <= Accumulator + Input;                          
                    end if;
                end if;
        end process Process_Integrate;
        
        Output <= Accumulator;
        
end architecture Behavioural;
```

**UPDATE 2:**

What can I say? Not much except that it does work in simulation. It simply doesn't work in hardware.

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.Std_logic_1164.all;
use IEEE.Numeric_Std.all;

entity Integrator_tb is
end;

architecture bench of Integrator_tb is

  component Integrator
    generic(    Max : integer   := integer'high;
                Min : integer   := integer'low);
    port(   Input       : in    integer;
            Output      : out   integer := 0;
            Sample      : in    std_logic;
            Reset       : in    std_logic;
            Clock       : in    std_logic);
  end component;

  signal Input: integer;
  signal Output: integer := 0;
  signal Sample: std_logic;
  signal Reset: std_logic;
  signal Clock: std_logic;

  constant clock_period: time := 10 ns;
  signal stop_the_clock: boolean;

begin   

  -- Insert values for generic parameters !!
  uut: Integrator generic map ( Max    => 1000 ,
                                Min    =>  -1000)
                     port map ( Input  => Input,
                                Output => Output,
                                Sample => Sample,
                                Reset  => Reset,
                                Clock  => Clock );

  clocking: process
  begin
  
    Sample <= '1';
    Input <= 1;
  
    while not stop_the_clock loop
      if Output >= 17 then
        Input <= -3;
      elsif Output <= -23 then
        Input <= 3;
      end if;
    
      Clock <= '0', '1' after clock_period / 2;
      wait for clock_period;
    end loop;
    wait;
  end process;

end;
```

[image]

**UPDATE 3:**

I rewrote the internals to use signed and it is still unable to decrease in synthesis. Works in simulation though. Maybe something is wrong with the hardware wrapper. Don't know what that would be though since I have put it in scenarios where it responds to both increasing and decreasing.

```
architecture Behavioural of Integrator is

    signal Accumulator      : signed(31 downto 0)   := (others => '0');
    signal Converted_Input  : signed(31 downto 0)   := (others => '0');
    
    begin
    
        Process_Input : process(Clock)
            begin
                if rising_edge(Clock) then
                    Converted_Input <= to_signed(Input,32);
                end if;
        end process Process_Input;
        
        Process_Integrate : process(Clock)
            begin
                if rising_edge(Clock) then
                    if Reset then
                        Accumulator <= (others => '0');
                    elsif Sample then
                        Accumulator <= Accumulator + Converted_Input;
                    end if;
                end if;
        end process Process_Integrate;
        
        Process_Output : process(Clock)
            begin
                if rising_edge(Clock) then
                    Output <= to_integer(Accumulator);
                end if;
        end process Process_Output;
        
end architecture Behavioural;
```

Comment: add a brief testbench to the question... (this is only valid VHDL in VHDL-2008 or newer, thanks to its (ab)use of OUT ports; so it's worth also mentioning which toolchain + version you are using)

Comment: @user_1818839 Part of the problem is Vivado doesn't support 2008 testbench so I am testing on hardware. I'll try the regular pre-2008 method and see if that changes anything. I've noticed other strange behaviour with this particular chunk which I haven't asked about yet. Overflow, for example, seems impossible to stop. Doesn't matter how I check or what range limits I use. And predividers on the integral output produce inexplicable, confounding behaviour.

Comment: Pre-2008, making `Output` a buffer should suffice. (I've also found Vivado 2018.2 allowed me to do the whole process in VHDL-2008 then reporting the IP packager doesn't support 2008! Also, older Xilinx ISIM runs by default with overflow checks turned OFF! Nasty... But there SHOULD be an option somewhere to turn them on. TL/DR your code LOOKS OK, I believe you're fighting tools.

Comment: @user_1818839 Wait, what? There are overflow checks? I've been implementing all those manually when I need an integer to saturate. Though usually everything I do only increments or decrements by 1 and the limits are nowhere near integer'high or integer'low. But in this case neither is true so I thought it was overflowing in the overflow checking math itself but no approaches seem to change behaviour. Even making the limit far from integer'high or low.

Comment: Use ranged integer subtypes and you SHOULD get overflow errors (in simulation : best practice is to debug in sim before moving to hardware). But Xilinx ISIM (and probably Vivado's XSIM) doesn't bother, unless you turn them on. Synthesis assumes the design is already debugged, so overflow checks is one of the things it can omit from the hardware it makes. Saturation is different : if you need saturated arithmetic you do have to roll your own. (I'd look at declaring my own type and override "+" to provide it)

Comment: If you think it's worth formulating a good question ( + failing testcase) about either overflows or saturation, or both, go ahead and post it.

Comment: It's been a while. So, just an opinion. Anyway, "Output" is a port with "out" attribute. Wonder, why it allows "Output + Input" (feed-back) operation. It does not sound like VHDL would do. I would have a register/buffer (signal?) for the operation.

Comment: @jay It's something new in VHDL-2008. You can't read from an output port internally prior to 2008.

Comment: @DKNguyen It sounds like you became the test-bench/victim. :-) Wonder if you tried that olden (97?) style, just to prove you are the victim.

Comment: "Buffer" ports are highly unrecommended in Vivado guides for PAR.

Comment: @MituRaj If Vivado doesn't support buffer ports at least this well, it's considerably worse than I thought. However it wouldn't stop the alternative of using an internal signal for the integrator, and copying it to the output.

Comment: However the copy `Output <= Accumulator;` must be a concurrent statement to avoid the additional cycle delay in the UPDATEd question.

Comment: @user_1818839 Yes. It doesn't matter in this particular application though. I put it inside because of all the strange weirdness I've been experiencing. I literally fed negative numbers directly into it yesterday and it still doesn't work. At best the integral remains the same. Adding or subtracting a negative number, but subtracting a positive number or adding a negative number does not work. It is very strange that it cannot ever decrease.

Comment: Does it work for you in simulation?

Comment: @user_1818839 I haven't been able to simulate it because it was originally in VHDL-2008 and I recently found out Vivado  doesn't support simulation for that so I've been testing on hardware. I may have to rip it out of everything and change it so I can simulate it.

Comment: Seriously, you're doing things the hard way if you don't get it working in simulation first. (Though I come back to it possibly being a tools issue : one thing I'd try is numeric_std.signed, just in case Vivado doesn't synthesise integers properly; though there's no excuse for that. And I'm eager to hear your eventual findings)

Comment: @user_1818839 Updated post with my findings. I'll try signed in synthesis and see if it changes anything because it seems like I'm going to have to trick the tools at this point. I could also punch everything into ISE and test it on older hardware but damn. That's a lot of work.

Comment: OK now you have a testcase with testbench, I believe this is worth reporting to Xilinx (user forums, as Webcases are long gone) as a likely tool bug. You could try post-synth simulation (you'll need a simple wrapper component to convert the post-synth netlist port types back to integer, and possibly add timing delays. Add that wrapper to the testcase). If that works, repeat with post-PAR netlist. Hopefully one of these will replicate the behaviour making a strong argument for a bug.  NOTE ... I never recommend post-synth or post-PAR simulation ... except when chasing tool bugs.

Comment: But *what exactly are you seeing* when it fails in hardware? Your ports are still declared as "Integer", right? So how many pins are on your ports? What exact values are you seeing in the hardware when this fails? *The actual binary arithmetic is exactly the same* between signed and unsigned numbers, so there must be something else weird going on here. Looking at the exact values seen in hardware is the best place to start.

Comment: @Mr.Snrub I am unable to view actual numbers in hardware. All I can really do is produce PWM pulses whose duty is proportional to the integral. I mentioned in my title and body what the failure is: "*It can hold its value or increase, but it never decreases even when fed with negative inputs.*" In other words, feeding negative inputs produces the same effect as zero input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My money is on the problem existing somewhere in the hardware wrapper, but that's actually beside the point.

Your best bet in debugging is to *view the exact values of the input and output and see how the design is responding*. In comments you state that you are "unable to view the actual numbers in hardware" but I think this still can be done, and it's vitally important that you do. Two (of likely many) possible ways to attack this problem:

**Heavyweight Option: Use an embedded logic analyzer**

Xilinx offers the [ChipScope ILA](https://www.xilinx.com/products/intellectual-property/chipscope_ila.html) logic analyzer which can be embedded inside the FPGA itself. While I have not personally used this analyzer, I have used the Intel (formerly Altera) [SignalTap II](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/programmable/quartushelp/13.0/mergedProjects/program/ela/ela_view_using.htm) and it's reasonable to assume the two have all the same features. My impression of the SignalTap II was that it consumed a lot of FPGA resources and was a real pain in the neck to learn and use, but in the end it was well worth it! Being able to view all the internal signals of the functioning design is just such a huge benefit. The SignalTap II (and probably the ChipScope as well) interface is over the JTAG port, so it doesn't require reallocating any pins on the FPGA device; as long as you have JTAG port access you're all set.

**Lightweight Option: Create a throwaway design to test some assumptions**

In the comments you note that you can "produce PWM pulses whose duty is proportional to the integral." I take this to mean that you have the `Output` port of your design connected to a circuit that generates a PWM. So, why not create a super-primitive VHDL file that simply assigns `Output <= Input` (as either a concurrent or a synchronous process)? Then you can get a look at what your design is seeing for the value of `Input`. Sure, it's a PWM and not an actual digital reading, but you can decrease your input from a large positive value down to zero and then down to some negative values; does the PWM decrease accordingly or does it "clamp" at the zero value? (Or if the PWM is an unsigned value, does it suddenly jump to 100% duty cycle to correspond to the "-1" value of 0xFFFFFFFF?)

In your description of the problem you say that the output never decreases; so it sounds like something in your hardware wrapper or test code(?) may be "clamping" the value to zero. Performing this basic test will help you to at least prove or disprove that hypothesis.

Comment: The PWM duty was already tested to be able to decrease and increase based from 0 to 100 and 100 back to 0 again which is why I only bring up that it might be the wrapper up so late. As far as I am concerned it has been tested. I do have an 8-channel scope I can use as a logic analyzer but it's still a PITA.

Comment: So I directly fed numbers to my integrator using the scope as a logic analyzer and it actually does work...what that means is that for some reason it is not liking *exact* way I am producing the input. Basically a signal that is a difference of two other signals. However, explicit testing of this shows no problems either.

Comment: Okay, so it appears that the problem is some overflow saturation logic in the subtraction of the two signals prior to being fed into the input of the integrator. I had looked at this previously and could have sworn I had checked things with it completely removed. Apparently not. Though, I don't really understand why it's doing what it's doing but at least now I know which lines are doing it.

Comment: So, if I'm reading correctly, you are saying there's a problem somewhere in the VHDL code... but VHDL code that hasn't been provided here. Sounds like another good question to ask the EE.SE community :-)

Answer (score 2):

Rewriting in non-VHDL-2008 style (output port should become buffer, and add explicit level tests to std_logic signals)

```
    library IEEE;
    use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;

    entity Integrator is
               
    port(   Input       : in    integer;
            Output      : buffer   integer := 0;
            Sample      : in    std_logic;  --clock enable
            Reset       : in    std_logic;  --reset 'Output' to zero
            Clock       : in    std_logic);
            
    end entity Integrator;

    architecture Behavioural of Integrator is
    
    begin
    
        Process_Integrate : process(Clock)
            begin
                if rising_edge(Clock) then
                    if Reset = '1' then
                        Output <= 0;
                    elsif Sample = '1' then
                        Output <= Output + Input;
                    end if;
                end if;
        end process Process_Integrate;
   end architecture Behavioural;
```

and adding a simple testbench

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;

entity Integrator_TB is
end Integrator_TB;

architecture Test of Integrator_TB is

signal Input       : integer;
signal Output      : integer;
signal Sample      : std_logic := '1'; 
signal Reset       : std_logic; 
signal Clock       : std_logic := '0';

begin

DUT : entity work.Integrator
    port map( Input => Input,
            Output  => Output,
            Sample  => Sample,
            Reset   => Reset,
            Clock   => Clock);

   Reset <= '1', '0' after 20 ns;
   Clock <= not Clock after 10 ns;
   Input <= 1, -1 after 100 ns;

   Watch : Process(Output) is
   begin
      Report "Output = " & integer'image(Output) severity Note;
   end Process;

   Stop : Process is
   begin
      wait for 200 ns;
      Report "Test complete" severity Failure;
   end Process;   

end Test;
```

we can see the code is fine.

> brian@Sparrowhawk:~/Projects/ghdl/play$ ghdl -a integrator.vhd
> brian@Sparrowhawk:~/Projects/ghdl/play$ ghdl -a integrator_tb.vhd
> brian@Sparrowhawk:~/Projects/ghdl/play$ ghdl -e Integrator_TB
> brian@Sparrowhawk:~/Projects/ghdl/play$ ghdl -r Integrator_TB
> integrator_tb.vhd:30:7:@0ms:(report note): Output = 0
> integrator_tb.vhd:30:7:@30ns:(report note): Output = 1
> integrator_tb.vhd:30:7:@50ns:(report note): Output = 2
> integrator_tb.vhd:30:7:@70ns:(report note): Output = 3
> integrator_tb.vhd:30:7:@90ns:(report note): Output = 4
> integrator_tb.vhd:30:7:@110ns:(report note): Output = 3
> integrator_tb.vhd:30:7:@130ns:(report note): Output = 2
> integrator_tb.vhd:30:7:@150ns:(report note): Output = 1
> integrator_tb.vhd:30:7:@170ns:(report note): Output = 0
> integrator_tb.vhd:30:7:@190ns:(report note): Output = -1
> integrator_tb.vhd:36:7:@200ns:(report failure): Test complete

Which leaves tools issues...

Answer (score -6):

The code is just badly designed, there are no else conditions on the if statements. Without the else conditions, your compiler is susceptible to producing LATCHES which then limits the timing capability of your circuit.

Your reset should also be asynchronous unless you're looking for a synchronous design, there are also no conditions on the signals when evaluating in the if statement.

Apart from that i don't see why it shouldn't work, its not a particularly complex circuit

Comment: Are you sure about that statement about latches if it is a clocked process? Because in my experience and understanding is that inferred latches only happen if it is an asynchronous circuit (i.e. not flip-flops triggered off the clock edge) but not when it is clock triggered but i could be wrong. I doubt it though because then registers would be impossible other sources also seem to support that. Usually my resets are asynchronous but in this case it was was made to purposefully made to be synchronous.

Comment: Yes latches are inferred when the lock signal is not present on the sensitivity list. But instead the triggering signal. However, its still best practice to cover all conditions when designing if statement for readability. In the clock process, latches will not generate because even if your triggering signals change, it will have no effect until the rising edge. but as mentioned, its always est practice to cover all possible conditions.

Comment: Are you saying you would actually write ''else Accumulator <= Accumulator'' or 'else Output <= Output''

Comment: And also, because you're using priority logic. The reset condition should be placed last since it is rarely triggered in comparison to your sample signal

Comment: An empty else clause is fine. Explicitly it shows that other than the defined conditions, any other conditions will trigger nothing. You'll find at top companies, that recruiters hate these kind of implicit programmers because they create bugs in code and you are required to make a number of assumptions in order to attempt to understand it. Especially when the code is complex with millions of lines, you need to improve the readability

Comment: I'm fine with verbosity. I just never considered anyone would want it that verbose. Like if I go "if n = '0' then [...]" I sit there wondering whether I should go "else" or elsif n = '1'

Comment: As long as your colleagues are not required to make a number of assumptions when you're not available for contact then its fine. I'm supposing you've never worked on large projects with millions of lines of code. Readability takes precedence over performance

Comment: No, I just do R&D.

Comment: Regarding latches, in the properly structured clock process it the question, this answer is just plain wrong.

Comment: This is so wrong unless you mention the context. And sensitivity list has NOTHING TO DO with Synthesis.

Comment: Mitu Raj, please explain why you think the sensivitiy list has no effect on the synthesis of LATCHES. IM interested

Comment: It's all over synthesis guides, read them. Synthesisers IGNORE sensitivity list. It exists only to avoid synthesis-simulation mismatches.